# Кастомный оператор сравнения ==

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Здравствуйте! В Unity3D реализована возможность опустить оператор сравнения когда объект проверяется на null, т.е. вместо if(instance != null) можно писать просто if(instance).

Т.е. получается type-to-bool.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html

Как такое реализовать для своих классов в C#?

Comment: "Для своих"  - имеется в виду, которые не унаследованы от  MonoBehaviour ? Которые просто `class MyClass { ... }` ?

Comment: возможно можно сделать типа такого https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358498/6104996 - только со своим  ̶б̶л̶э̶к̶д̶ж̶е̶к̶о̶м̶ ̶и̶ ̶д̶а̶м̶а̶м̶и̶  логикой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, спасибо! Это оно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала предупреждение. Не стоит делать из C# C++. Если вы разрешите такие конструкции, вы получите «впридачу» и типичные ошибки языка C++. Например, присваивание внутри `if` внезапно начнёт компилироваться: `if (a = b)`, и компилятор не будет находить за вас такие вот проблемы.

Кроме того, такой код неидиоматичен: код вида `if (variable)` для переменной, тип которой не `bool`, заставит ваших коллег удивлённо поднять брови.

Поэтому я бы советовал использовать такой код лишь в учебных/развлекательных целях.

---

Проще всего использовать неявное преобразование в `bool`:

```
class Test
{
    public static implicit operator bool(Test p) => p != null;
}
```

Имея это, вы сможете легко писать код в духе C++:

```
Test t1 = new Test(), t2 = null;
if (t1)
    Console.WriteLine("t1 != null");
if (!t2)
    Console.WriteLine("t2 == null");
if (t1 && t2)
    Console.WriteLine("t1 != null && t2 != null");
if (!t1 || !t2)
    Console.WriteLine("t1 == null || t2 == null");
```

Другой путь, более сложный — использовать операторы `true` и `false`.

Пример:

```
class Test
{
    public static bool operator true(Test p) => p != null;
    public static bool operator false(Test p) => p == null;
}
```

С этим можно писать проверки наподобие

```
Test t1 = new Test();
if (t1)
    Console.WriteLine("t1 != null");
```

Но `!t1` уже не скомпилируется. Вам придётся писать оператор `!`. Чтобы работало `&&` и `||`, вам придётся определить и другие операторы:

```
class Test
{
    public static bool operator true(Test p) => p != null;
    public static bool operator false(Test p) => p == null;
    public static bool operator ! (Test p) => p == null;
    public static Test operator & (Test t1, Test t2) => t1 == null ? null : t2;
    public static Test operator | (Test t1, Test t2) => t1 != null ? t1 : t2;
    public static bool operator & (Test t1, bool t2) => t1 == null ? false : t2;
    public static bool operator | (Test t1, bool t2) => t1 != null ? true : t2;
}
```

Этот путь мне кажется более тяжёлым.

Comment: О боже, как я мог пропустить такое! Не знал что такой оператор можно переопределять. 1ый вариант который. Спасибо! А ведь мог догадаться... А насчет 'неидеоматичности' конструкции, то в Unity3d это очень распространенный стиль, т.е. писать без явного указания оператора сравнения.

Comment: @Nemonymous то, что там разрешено писать `if (someObject)` - не значит, что распространенный стиль. Честно говоря я вообще ни разу ни в одном коде такое не видел. А повидал я не мало. Всегда все пишут `if (someObject != null)`. Так что такое утверждать - как-то неправильно

Comment: @vladd, вы смотрели блоги разработчиков игр на Unity3d? Или самих разработчиков движка? Там такой оператор имеет чуток другую реализацию, так как там все 'fake null', но не суть... В общем, я много кода читал из этой 'сферы' скажем так, и там много где встречается такая конструкция. Даже в документации.

Comment: @Nemonymous: Окей, в любом случае, теперь вы знаете, что там под капотом.

Comment: +1 к тому, что не стоит так писать. Все места которые я видел с подобным стилем были написаны еще в бородатые года и все удевлялись потом с этого кода.